# How to use the word bullshit?

Tags: grammar

Can you tell me the differences between, "this is such bullshit" and "it's such a bullshit"??  Why there isn't "a" in the first sentence ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's a mass noun, and should thus not be used with a determiner, so the second example is incorrect.

Comment: BS is a mass noun: there's so much of it about.  Tons of it, everywhere.